# I want to optimize my URL for SEO purpose. Using Umbraco ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, url-rewriting, umbraco

```
<rule name="blog categories" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="/?blog/categories/([^/]+)/" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="/blog/cat={R:1}" />
            </rule>
```

This is the code in web.config might be helpful to you. 
my url : capcom/?page=2
I want to remove '?' from the url or '/'.

Comment: Can you please provide a couple of examples which redirects do you want to achieve. For example: `page/A/url` -> `pageB/url`

Comment: /pk/automotive-motorcycles/?page=1

Comment: To which url do you want redirect it?

Answer (score 0):

To use urls like .../page/2 instead of ...?page=2 you can add this rule to the rewrite section of your web.config:

```
<rule name="pagination" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.+)/page/([0-9]+)$" />
  <action url="{R:1}?page={R:2}" type="Rewrite" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you just put a canonical url in your , which doesn't have the query string on it. That might look like:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="@Model.Current.Url">
```

Comment: Canonicals are pretty useful. However, I'm pretty sure this basic example will miss out on things like query strings (which may influence what is rendered on the page such as if there is pagination). Setting up proper canonicals can be as difficult as setting up proper redirects.

Comment: You're right, smarty pants. This is a simple example, but you don't always want to have every page indexed by Google, it can create two many indexed urls. If you want to have the page in it as well then you can just use:
`<link rel="canonical" href='@string.Concat(Model.Current.Url, "?p=", Request.QueryString["p"])'>`